# Update fragment TextView after database update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am looking to update a textview in a fragment after a database update has been made.

I have MainActivity which hosts MainFragment

MainFragment has a TextView in it which is the SUM of column a in my database.

In MainActivity I have a button which i press that opens a dialog where i can add a value to the column a in the database.  The dialog appears over the top of the fragment, but when I press OK and send that new value to the database, and then try to update the textview it is not updating.

I have the following in my fragment but I guess it is never getting called.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("onResume", "here");
        int balance = db.getSum();
        tvBalanceDollar.setText(Integer.toString(balance));
    }
```

Where could I put the db.getSum(); and the setText to update that field after the dialog is closed?

EDIT:

Does the fragment ever get paused, or the view recreated after a dialog from the activity is closed?

Comment: Why dont you set that text view value on click of that dialog? database operation is quite fast enough to load and those data read again from your database until onResume method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, onResume() is not the best way to place that. I think the best way should be starting the dialog window using `startActivityForResult(intent, your_requestCode)`.

Then, in the dialog when you finish adding the value to your database and want to return to your activity, do:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

And back in your main activity use onActivityResult() to update the textview:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case your_requestCode: {
            //...
            DO YOUR STUFF HERE
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

To update fragment's textview from main activity, you should implement a callback interface.

```
public interface FragmentCallback {
    public void modifyTextView(String text);
}
```

Then:

```
FragmentCallback fragCall;
```

An inside the previously commented onActivityResult:

```
fragCall.modifyTextView(yourText);
```

Finally you implement the callback listener on your fragment:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCallback {
```

And inside the method you change the textview's text:

```
@Override
public void modifyTextView(String text) {
    yourTextView.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just override the onStart method of fragment and call the particular textView to update text in that method.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    textView.setText(/* update method */);
    //TODO call your method here.
}
```